# Talend Post Service

Tags: talend

I'm trying to **post** data into 2 tables which are **`patient table`** and **`phone table`**.

These 2 tables mapped by another table **`patient_phone`**. This table contains `patient_id(**patient table**)` and `phone_id(phone table)`.

So I have to join 3 tables to post some fields to both patient table and phone table.

I did it for **`get`** data, it's working fine.These images show how I did to **`get`** data

[image: 1]

and

[image: 3]

But I didn't find any solution, how to join these tables for posting. This  shows how I tried to **post** data:

[image: 2]
Help me to get the solution. Thanks in advance